# Problem: onLocationListener only called once

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm trying to get an accurate value of current position, much like a car locator app: You use `GPS` position to tag where your car is.

The problem is that onLocationListener is only called once, and that first fix might not be as accurate as I want. Therefore I want to listen to, say five updates to get a more accurate position.
I register for updates like this:
**RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsLocationListener);**

If I'm moving I get a lot of updates, But when standing still I only get one update.

How to force it to get more updates even when standing still to get a more accurate position?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in line-of-sight, you would get location updates at a much frequent interval. In case you are inside somewhere, where your device can not have a line-of-sight to the GPS satellites above, you would not any location fix and hence no location updates.